# How can i count x from a row ? Excell

Tags: excel, xml

I am trying to count how many of "x" are  only on rows that have "192"(example) and I don't have any idea how to do that.
I was trying with =COUNTIFS(B:B,"192",2:17,"X ") with no success .
I can see how many of "192 " are in the table with =COUNTIF(B:B,"192").

I have a photo of the table here :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below formula-

```
=SUM((B2:B15=192)*(C2:M15="x"))
```

You may need array `CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER` for older versions of excel.

[image]

Comment: it works but just for B2:B15  . I want to have a bigger range like all the column  b

Comment: @EduardIvanov Then change parameter like `=SUM((B:B=192)*(C:M="x"))`

Comment: Don't use entire column references though! Limit the range, either using a dynamic named range or else a suitably low upper bound.